# node.setAttribute causes INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas, setattribute

I have the following code in a function:

```
  this.HtmlRef = document.createElement( "canvas" );

  if (!this.HtmlRef)
  {
    return false;
  }

  this.HtmlRef.appendChild(  document.createTextNode( "Your browser doesn't support dynamic graphic drawings (Canvas)!" )  );

  var Width = document.createAttribute( "width" );
  var Height = document.createAttribute( "height" );
  Width.nodeValue = 0;
  Height.nodeValue = 0;

  this.HtmlRef.setAttribute(Width);  /* error */
  this.HtmlRef.setAttribute(Height); /* error */
```

I have also tried to change the names of Width and Height but no success!
The whole error message:

> Uncaught Error: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5

Thanks.

The Solution is to use ***setAttributeNode*** instead of setAttribute

Comment: You can also see this error if you use `document.createElement('#document')` (or with `createElementNS`); this may occur if you naively try to clone an entire `Document` instead of the root node. The solution is to start cloning at the `node.documentElement` (the root).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use setAttributeNode() instead of setAttribute()